# Why does the increase in velocity result in decrease in pressure in a flow? Are there any explanations behind?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, flow

So I have been searching for this answer that why would increase in velocity result in pressure drop and found no explanation, please help, thanks!

Comment: Check out Bernoulli's equation, and look at the terms involving velocity.

Answer (score 3):

If the fluid is accelerating, the upstream force has to be higher than the downstream force.

Answer (score 2):

It is due to the conservation of energy. Pressure times volume is energy and kinetic energy is (obviously) energy. To conserve energy if kinetic energy increases then pressure must decrease (or the energy must go somewhere else).

Comment: Thanks, is there any other explanation for this phenomenon? Any quantum mechanically perspective?

Comment: Why would there be a quantum mechanical explanation? This is a classical physics question and a classical physics scenario.

Comment: There will definitely be an molecular explanation